# Remote object in flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, mobile-application, remoteobject

Can anyone explain me,
First of all is it possible to use remote object in Flex mobile application?
If so then what could be the issue for getting following exception?

> Error detail: "Channel.Connect.Failed error The application name
>   specified during connect is invalid."

```
FaultString: "Send failed 
 in - [RemoteObject  destination="VuetalkerLogin" source="VueTalkerDotnet.VueTalkerContact" channelSet="[ChannelSet weborb-rtmp ]"]"
```

Here things to be noted is the same function is to be called properly if I call it using 
NetConnection.call();

Secondly,
When I am trying to call the same source in Flex web application that remote object invocation works properly.

So can anyone guide me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The "application name invalid" probably means that at the FMS server you don't have a sub-dir of that name (which you use in the connect() call) in ..../applications dir.

Or that you don't have a main.asc file in that sub-dir

Comment: Thanxs. Well there was an issue in my server side script which was being thrown on flex side as this exception. Anyways thanks for the response.